# Играть "в бильярд" или "на бильярде"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Играть в бильярд" или "играть на бильярде"?
Как будет правильно?

Comment: См мнение Грамоты: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti?id=36_21&layout=item

Answer (score 4):

"Сейчас же принято говорить "играть В бильярд", подразумевая исключительно саму игру"
©http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_21

Вынужден не согласиться с уважаемой мной "Справкой" на Грамоте.
Всё несколько сложнее и неоднозначнее.

*Мы сыграли с Талем десять партий
В преферанс, в очко и на бильярде.*

©Высоцкий

Не думаю, что форма "на бильярде" - устаревшая. Как минимум - своего рода профжаргон. Сами бильярдисты играют именно "**на** бильярде". Посмотрите, в сети постоянно встречается "обучение игре на бильярде", "чемпионат по игре на бильярде" и т. д.

Тут вот какая штука. С точки зрения самих бильярдистов игры "в бильярд" не существует. Играть можно в восьмерку, русскую пирамиду, три шара, снукер... И всё это игры - **на бильярде**.

Answer (score 2):

"Играть на бильярде" - выражение устаревшее, встречающееся в русской классике. Например, у Пушкина:
*И после, дома целый день, один, в расчеты погруженный,

Он на бильярде в два шара играет с самого утра.*
Тут имелась в виду не игра, а сам бильярдный стол.
Сейчас же принято говорить "играть В бильярд", подразумевая исключительно саму игру.

Answer (score 1):

Не согласен, что устаревшее. Как любитель бильярда, мы сейчас играем именно *на* бильярде, но *в* русскую американку. По крайне мере, так говорим мы на Украине в городе Николаев в кругу своих друзей.

Что же касается тех кто играет *в* бильярд, то это сродни анекдоту про один кофе и один булочка.

Comment: Ну с анекдотом это вы слишком уж грубо.  
Играющих в бильярд можно заподозрить только в незнании бильярдного сленга, но никак не русского языка. В карты тоже можно играть в покер, очко или преферанс, но это не мешает играть именно в карты. С точки зрения простого смертного "играть в бильярд" - такой же гипероним для русской американки, снукера и двух шаров, как "играть в карты".

Answer (score 1):

Бильярд — это игра. А площадка, на которой происходит игра, называется бильярдный стол. Так же как и футбольное поле, хоккейная коробка, теннисный корт и т.д. Поэтому ***играть на бильярде*** — это сленг, исключительно субъективный. С точки зрения правил логики и русского языка правильно говорить: **играть *в бильярд***, и — если кому-то хочется, — **на бильярдном столе.**

Comment: Все бы ничего, но отсылка к неясным правилам "логики и русского языка" нуждается в конкретизации. Хотелось бы узнать, что это за "правила" такие. "Играть на скрипке" - тоже не по логике?

Answer (score 0):

Бильярд, в принципе, это сам стол. На нём можно делать всё, что угодно, не только играть. Правильно - "на бильярде" (реже - "на биллиарде").

Comment: Dimmon, здесь обычно ценятся более аргументированные ответы. Собвственное мнение (имха) - тоже, конечно неплохо, но не настолько, чтобы ей опровергать сказанное ранее.

Answer (score 0):

*Играть на бильярде в снукер*.
Вы же не станете говорить: "*Я играю в компьютер*",
вы скажете: "*Я играю на компьютере в покер*".
Так же надо говорить и о бильярде.

Answer (score -1):

бильяд - это площадка НА которой играют (стол, "поляна"). Слово двукоренное как "хоккейное поле", а НА хоккейном поле можно играть и В хоккей, и В догонялки при желании, и можно поставить стол и играть В карты. Так же и НА бильярде можно играть в разные игры: пул, американка...
Так же как играть ПО дороге, но соревноваться В скорости или В дрифте.

Comment: Слово двукоренное как "хоккейное поле"? ======Как «хоккейное поле» здесь стало словом, и как «двухкоренное» стало «двукоренным»?

Answer (score -1):

Если допустить, что игра под названием "бильярд" есть, то можно играть в бильярд. Но при этом никто не запрещает играть на бильярде в карты или... в бильярд.